# Inconsistent Python tag formatting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

There's [python3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3) and [python2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.6), but [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) breaks this pattern. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 11):

Done, but a bit differently from how you asked. 
I did the following renames:

- [python2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.6) -> [python-2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6)
- [python3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3) -> [python-3.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x)

So now all names have dashes. This is in line with how they do it over [at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), where they have a lot of volume of Python questions,
and I guess this scheme works well for them. The old names are left as synonyms.

Comment: No problem, fine by me. I don't know the standards, I was just wondering about the inconsistencies. Thanks!

Comment: @BCdotWEB Very well spotted, thanks for pointing it out!