# Can we constrict the [python-2.*] tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I would like to suggest the following:

1. Rename [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) -> [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
2. Synonymize [python-2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) -> [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

This is as we don't have individual Python 3 tags, such as [python-3.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-3.6). But we do however have version tags for Python 2, such as [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7). These version tags however don't incorporate all Python 2 versions into them - what should a user that has Python 2.5 code tag their question as?

---

Similar questions:

This is like the questions "[Is it time for the [python] to become extinct?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5451)" and "[Synonymization proposal for version-specific language tags](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2168)". However I don't wish for all the Python version tags to be incorporated into the [python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. It is only the Python 2 versions into a Python 2 tag.

Whilst somewhat similar "[Inconsistent Python tag formatting](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6033)" is why I chose to use the tag [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x), so that our tags stay consistent.

There are benefits for situations like "[(Optionally) add Python sub tags to questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7007)". When I tag a question as a Python 2 question, I always use [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7), as it's unlikely to be another Python 2 version. This should also help in cases where users forget that [python-2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) is a tag, such as in the answers and comments below the above question.

[Under this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2237) in 2014, this question was asked and our second highest 2.7 answer said:

> @nhgrif I think that that would be a good move. There is little benefit to distinguishing between Python 2.6 and 2.7.  – [200_success ♦](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) [Aug 6 '14 at 22:22](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2168#comment5731_2237)

---

And so can we make the tag [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)?

Comment: 1) What would be the benefit from this? 2) How will we avoid confusion in the process? There are major differences between 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7. True, we won't encounter them much, but I have no clue what this will do to old questions.

Comment: Surely there's a [*Snakes on a Plane*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0417148/) pun to make here...

Comment: @Jamal Since the name is actually derived from Monty Python and that group being famous for being punny: a pun could easily be made, but in a different direction ;-)

Comment: In case some were wondering, for comparison's sake, how Stack Overflow does tag language versioning, [see this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/709821) (also includes C# and Java for reference)

Comment: @Mast 1) I've said a couple of reasons above, consistency with Python 3.x, not incorporating Python 2.5 another. 2) We have major changes in Python 3.x and I don't think we encounter this problem. However if we do I'd like to know! :) 3) There are 18 Python-2.6 questions that will be the most affected, I'm happy to personally put a disclaimer of some sort on them all.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes!

I think that is very reasonable, for 2 reasons:

1. As you stated, we don't have individual tags for Python 3.5, 3.6, etc. and having [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) would be consistent.
2. While Python 2.6 has [some significant differences](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#what-s-new-in-python-2-6) compared to 2.5, namely new packages such as `multiprocessing` and `json`, as well as some compatibility module `future_builtins` incorporating some Python 3 functionality, it is backwards compatible to 2.5 and prior version, so any reviewer could say to someone using Python < 2.6, "you should update your package to the backwards compatible Python 2.6 and use *feature X* instead of [...]"

So as far as I am concerned, I am in favor and believe that it would make things simpler for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes, except:

Go ahead with the rename, but don't synonymize until all 2.6 and lower questions have explicit mentions in the question (regardless of the tag) it's targeting 2.6.

For reasons half the Python community pretends not to understand, a version is very important in Python. Sometimes you can't/won't/shouldn't upgrade and this should be respected.

If we go this route and nobody volunteers, I'll personally see to it the latter is done correctly.

Comment: I was going to do this if we got the [tag:python-2.x] - however won't if we won't. I commented the following in response to one of your questions above "3) There are 18 Python-2.6 questions that will be the most affected, I'm happy to personally put a disclaimer of some sort on them all."