# Python 2.x merger bugs

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

After [the creation of the Python-2.x tag](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8407) there are a couple of bugs:

- The ['top users' page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/python-2.x/topusers) now doesn't show the correct information.
- [My profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401?tab=profile) shows the tag as Python-2.7.
- The [Python-2.x badge page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/252/python-2-x) shows the tag as Python 2.7. This can be seen [on the silver badges page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) too.

To note some features of the merger do work. [Filtering by Python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) does work.

Comment: @Mast What page did you get your pic from? As the link in the question shows the tags as [python-2.x] rather than [python-2.7].

Comment: 2.7 didn't cease to exist, so apparently there has been no rename.

Comment: Filtering for 2.x catches both 2.x and 2.7: [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyVOa.jpg)

Comment: @Mast Ah yes I scrolled down more I can see that too :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what I did to perform the merge requested in the meta-post you linked:

1. Synonymize [python-2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.6) into [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
2. Rename [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) into [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) (I botched that one)
3. Synonymize [python2.6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.6) into [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
4. Synonymize [python2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.7) into [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)
5. Synonymize [python2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python2.x) into [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x)

Source: [The Tag synonyms page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all)

I **guess** that the root cause of this issue might be in the order of the first two steps...

Some things that may explain the different behaviours:

- Renaming the tag did not merge it (??). There's 1k [python-2.7](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) questions, but only ~50 [python-2.x](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-2.x) questions
- Caching / Denormalization in the database?

I apparently just didn't use the rename tool correctly and botched something in the process... I have just now merged [python-2.7] into [python-2.x]. The inconsistencies you've seen should be fixed modulo caching.

Comment: This looks promising since Python-2.7 is no-longer on my profile. Hopefully it doesn't reset the acquisitions of the badges to today tho

Comment: @Peilonrayz are you seeing any other bugs surrounding this scenario, or have they been remedied by the Merge that Vogel did?

Comment: @Malachi Except the ones in the question and the above comment I've not seen any others. It has fixed the error Mast raised, and so I'm hoping the rest is just caching :)

Comment: @Peilonrayz Clear the Cache Then...lol!  lets find out!

Comment: Ok that's fixed everything, but broken [the history of the badges](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/badges/270/python-2-x) ):

Comment: Ugh... why can't it ever be easy...

Comment: Yeah, at least the more important things are fixed :) IMO this is now [meta-tag:status-completed]